# Unzipping larger files with PHP

Tags: php, unzip

I'm trying to unzip a 14MB archive with PHP with code like this:

```
    $zip = zip_open("c:\kosmas.zip");
    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
    $fp = fopen("c:/unzip/import.xml", "w");
    if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, "r")) {
     $buf = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
     fwrite($fp,"$buf");
     zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
     fclose($fp);
     break;
    }
   zip_close($zip);
  }
```

It fails on my localhost with 128MB memory limit with the classic "`Allowed memory size of blablabla bytes exhausted`". On the server, I've got 16MB limit, is there a better way to do this so that I could fit into this limit? I don't see why this has to allocate more than 128MB of memory. Thanks in advance.

**Solution:**
I started reading the files in 10Kb chunks, problem solved with peak memory usage arnoud 1.5MB.

```
        $filename = 'c:\kosmas.zip';
        $archive = zip_open($filename);
        while($entry = zip_read($archive)){
            $size = zip_entry_filesize($entry);
            $name = zip_entry_name($entry);
            $unzipped = fopen('c:/unzip/'.$name,'wb');
            while($size > 0){
                $chunkSize = ($size > 10240) ? 10240 : $size;
                $size -= $chunkSize;
                $chunk = zip_entry_read($entry, $chunkSize);
                if($chunk !== false) fwrite($unzipped, $chunk);
            }

            fclose($unzipped);
        }
```

Comment: What is the *uncompressed* size of the zip file?

Comment: Is using command line tools an option?

Comment: Uncompressed size is about 110MB. 
Unfortunately, using command line is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you read the whole file at once?

```
 $buf = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
 fwrite($fp,"$buf");
```

Try to read small chunks of it and writing them to a file.

Comment: That is exactly what I did and I'm gonna post the solution in a minute, if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

Just because a zip is less than PHP's memory limit & perhaps the unzipped is as well, doesn't take account of PHP's overhead generally and more importantly the memory needed to actually unzip the file, which whilst I'm not expert with compression I'd expect may well be a lot more than the final unzipped size.

Comment: Yes, but there always seems to be an alternative, i.e. I can ungzip much larger archive with peak memory usage lower than 1MB, I can parse 1.5GB xml file with peak memory usage lower than 3MB, why couldn't there be such alternative for zip files...

Answer (score 1):

For a file of that size, perhaps it is better if you use [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) instead:

```
shell_exec('unzip archive.zip -d /destination_path');
```

PHP must *not* be running in safe mode and you must have access to both shell_exec and unzip for this method to work.

**Update**:

Given that command line tools are not available, all I can think of is to create a script and send the file to a remote server where command line tools *are* available, extract the file and download the contents.

Comment: Unfortunately, command line tools are disabled by the server.

Comment: @Anax this is why PHP gets a bad wrap. Why should a production application ever need to run commandline args? This is the principle source of so many PHP worms.

Comment: The above command has worked for me. thanks @Anax

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_unzip($full_pathname){

    $unzipped_content = '';
    $zd = gzopen($full_pathname, "r");

    while ($zip_file = gzread($zd, 10000000)){
        $unzipped_content.= $zip_file;
    }

    gzclose($zd);

    return $unzipped_content;

}
```

Comment: Any explanation or reasoning behind this solution might be helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: Also, this has been answered **4** years ago.