# Extract big archive .zip ( > 2 GB) using PHP

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, zip, wamp

The following zip program works without any issues for smaller size files approximately few hundred MB. But when the .zip archives are bigger, the program showing **zip archive extraction failed**. I have increased mem size and exec time. **My file zip size is 2.30GB**. My code is:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '30000M');

function unzip_file($file, $destination)
{
    // create object
    $zip = new ZipArchive() ;
    // open archive
    if ($zip->open($file) !== true) {
        return false;
    }
    // extract contents to destination directory
    $zip->extractTo($destination);
    // close archive
    $zip->close();
        return true;
}

if (unzip_file($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/testarul/www.zip', $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/testarul/')) {
    echo 'zip archive extracted successfully';
} else {
    echo 'zip archive extraction failed';
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your error log?

Comment: You could try buffering the unzip process https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263129/unzipping-larger-files-with-php

Comment: Add `echo $zip->status;` underneath `$zip->extractTo($destination);` and try again. Tell us what it returned.

Comment: ....shell_exec?

Comment: shell_exec means? How to do that? @Progrock

Comment: **echo $zip->status;** Not showing anything, Zip file size is 2.30GB. @icecub

Comment: Nothing in error log @Tiffany